# React.js and Tomcat

Tags: spring, reactjs

I have a Spring MVC Web application which runs on Apache Tomcat Server. Someone created the front-end for this application with React.js and Redux and I need to integrate it in my project, but it is opened on port 3000 and Tomcat runs on port 8080. How can I do this? I do not know any React.

Comment: Is it spring boot ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what is going on here.

1. React is a client-side application
2. If it runs on port 3000, it's probably running on webpack-dev-server

React.js doesn't *run* on a port. The application server runs on a port.  You cannot *run* a React application. You can only *serve* an application written in react. React is a library. At the end of development, all you would get is an index.html and a (or a few) bundle.js files.

In order to serve React as a resource in your Spring MVC application, have a controller that returns React's index.html. If your react application has a react router, it will take over from there (subsequent url change in browser will not trigger server-side rendering).

My personal preference is to host react as a separate application and probably use express.js as the application server instead of tomcat.

[This lengthy article also touches on how to serve React's index.html using a controller. Which is basically the same as serving your JSP or webjars](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)

Answer (score 0):

If you using spring boot in `application.properties` write  `server.port=8080`. And if you using Spring you will have to change port in tomcat. In order to do so

```
.Go to tomcat>conf folder

.Edit server.xml

.Search "Connector port"

.Replace "8080" by your port number

.Restart tomcat server.
```